# fixed position is not relative to parent container in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

If we define a transform in the parent container the child position will inherit from the parent container in chrome and firefox but not in ie.

So what do I have to do for it to work in ie11 so it's always relative to the parent container?

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}

div.fixed2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class='fixed2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you need fixed element inside fixed element?

you can simply use `position: absolute` for the child i think. please check if this works for you.

if you really need both of them to be fixed, i think you can simple make 2 elements as siblings

here is the updated snippet

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
}

div.fixed2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class='fixed2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a `transform` value set on the first - this creates a new stacking context for `position:fixed` to be placed from - if you remove that then it will work properly. If you need to force things onto the GPU for performance then nest the element that needs it. [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform)

Comment: I don't think `transform` creates one on IE11. The container block of a fixed position element seems to always be the viewport, even if a parent has a transform.

Answer (score -1):

Please read up on the `position` property.  I suggest https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp as a good start.

Also, as a matter of good programming practice please avoid using words like `fixed` as a name for a class as this may be reserved.  Overwriting such can cause problems.  Also, please use more descriptive names.

If you want the inner `div` positioned relative to your outer `div` is suggest using code similar to the following...

```css
div.outerDiv
{
    background-color : red;
    border           : 3px solid #73AD21;
    height           : 100px;
    position         : fixed;
    top              : 100px;
    transform        : translate3d( 0, 0px, 0);
    width            : 300px;
}

div.innerDiv
{
    background-color : blue;
    border           : 3px solid #73AD21;
    height           : 100px;
    left             : 20px;
    position         : absolute;
    top              : 10px;
    width            : 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "outerDiv">
    <div class = "innerDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "reserved" class name - though some libraries use generic names like that (ie, jQueryUI provides `.clearfix`) - using an obvious name like this shouldn't cause any issues, but as always, the Chrome/Firefox/etc Inspector is your friend.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed means that the element is positioned against the window, not the parent element.

Just add "`left: 10px`" and you'll see that it's not positioned against the parent. In all brosers.

https://jsfiddle.net/4agxb8z4/

Comment: but then why it is taking position from parent in chrome or firefox. because if you are right then they should overlap because both have same top value.

Comment: @Mahi : No it doesn't. It's positioned due to `top:100px`.

Comment: @Pugazh both have top 100px .

Comment: @tomas why did you remove transform property in your fiddle

Comment: Fixed is relative to the window unless a parent element has transform then this is used instead - please check the spec - w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform

Comment: @Mahi 'cos the transformation also changed the position which confued me.